# Django - Downloading a file to local downloads folder

Tags: django, upload

In Django, I am trying to download an entire album into local "downloads" default folder on the client's PC. but how do I specify the target folder? currently, my code doesn't nothing.

from views.py:

```
def download_file(lfile):
    uploaded_file = lfile
    response = HttpResponse(uploaded_file.image, content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{lfile.fname}"'
    return response

def download_album(request, albumpk, albumowner):
    album = Category.objects.filter(id=albumpk)
    lfiles = Photo.objects.filter(category=albumpk)
    for lfile in lfiles:
        dfile = download_file(lfile)
    return redirect('albumlist', albumowner)
```